# Посчитать минимальное количество столбцов в матрице

Tags: c++, матрицы, ввод

[image: Матрица]

Матрица записана в текстовом файле, необходимо посчитать минимальное количество столбцов в матрице и заполнить двумерный массив обработанной матрицей (в моем случае необходимо заполнить двумерный массив, исключив последний столбец.) .

Неудачная реализация в моем коде:

```
`


int rows; // к-во строк
int col=0; // кол-во столбцов
string str;
int minCol=0;

while(!f.eof())
{
getline(f,str);
rows++;
istringstream ss(str);
int dat;
if (col>minCol) break;
else
 {
   col=0;
   while(ss>>dat)
   {
   col++;
   if (col>minCol)
      minCol=col;
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Видите ли, вот так - `f>>str` - вы считываете не строку, а одно слово...

Comment: Исправил условие, но опять же выводит количество строк и длину первой строки, а не минимальное количесто столбцов (минимальную длину строки)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> v;
    ifstream in("data");
    string buf;
    int min_size = INT_MAX;
    while(getline(in,buf))
    {
        vector<int> ln;
        istringstream is(buf);
        for(int d; is >> d;) ln.push_back(d);
        if (ln.size())
        {
            v.push_back(ln);
            if (min_size > ln.size()) min_size = ln.size();
        }
    }
    for(auto& ln: v) ln.resize(min_size);

    for(const auto& ln: v)
    {
        for(const auto& d: ln) cout << setw(3) << d << " ";
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```