# Подсчет количества ЧИСЕЛ в строке с переходом на новую строку

Tags: c++

[image: формат входных данных]

Необходимо посчитать количество чисел в строке (из файла на вход поступает матрица), после чего перейти на новую строку, посчитать количество чисел в строке и сравнить предыдущую с новым количеством чисел в строке. В результате надо вывести количество переходов на новую строку и вывести минимальное количество чисел в строке.

Неудачная реализация в моем коде:

```
     `
    string s;
    getline (f,s);
    int spaces = 0,
    realcol= 10;
    while(f.eof()!=0)
    {
       for(int i = 0; i < s.length();i++);
       {

        if(s[i] == ' ') spaces++;
       }
    spaces++;
    if(realcol > spaces) realcol = spaces;
       }


         cout<<realcol;
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117187/discussion-on-question-by-marlowism-------).

Comment: Тебе ж уже сегодня писали считывание этой штуковины. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1217375/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy позже узнал что <vector> запрещено использовать

Comment: Ну так дали бы в комментарии просьбу исправить ответ :) Вы же даже не попытались изменить код так, чтобы работать не с векторами! опять это  `while(f.eof()!=0)`... впрочем, в цикле вы ничего не читаете. Делаю вывод: вы в принципе не разбираетесь с тем, что вам ответили, а просто отправляете код преподу, не пытаясь понять, как он работает. Считаю, что перед нами чистейший случай требования сделать домашку без попыток поработать самому!

Comment: В прошлом вопросе вы хотели "*и заполнить двумерный массив обработанной матрицей (в моем случае необходимо заполнить двумерный массив, исключив последний столбец.)*" - собственно, только для этого я и применил вектор - для создания матрицы. Теперь, как я понимаю, это больше не требуется? Или быдет оченедной вопрос с невнятным кодом - а как теперь считать в матрицу?

Comment: @Harry  я лишь пытаюсь понять как делать данное мне задание (мне необходимо рассмотреть разные варианты реакции программы на заполнение матрицы пользователем) , лишь случай с "лишним" столбцом считается неверно, поэтому я и обращаюсь к вам с вопросом. По поводу "Ну так дали бы в комментарии просьбу исправить ответ :)"- я посчитал это не совсем корректным, поскольку ваше решение выдает верный результат.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш код можно переписать следующим образом:

```
string s;  //или int s
unsigned spaces{}, realcol = 1000;
while (f >> s) {
    ++spaces;
    //если достигли конца строки
    if (f.peek() == '\n') {
        //сравниваем
        if(spaces < realcol)
            realcol = spaces;
        //обнуляем счетчик
        spaces = 0;
    }
}
cout << realcol;
```

Comment: Только называть числа пробелами немного не очень)

Comment: @Qwertiy, и причем  пробел, кто о пробелах говорил?

Comment: Ну `spaces` так переводится ;) Можно, конечно, перевести как места, но что-то маловероятно в этом контексте. К тому же, автор явно в неё пробелы считал.

Comment: Кстати, кажется у тебя косяк если последняя строка не завершается переводом строки. Возможно, надо `f.peek() == '\n' || f.eof()`.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ах вы об этом!.. Я просто скопировал названия переменных, пусть ТС сам подумает насколько уместны эти названия. Вы правы.

Comment: большое спасибо!

Comment: @Qwertiy, а вот по поводу  f.eof() это лишнее, потому что если это условие выполнится, то состояния потока  не будет  good, и главное условие не выполнится.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, хм.. а как тогда? Я правильно понимаю, что в случае, когда самая короткая строка последняя и она не заканчивается переводом строки, выведется неверный результат?

Comment: @Qwertiy совершенно верно, когда самая короткая строка - последняя, программа выдает неверный результат

Comment: @Qwertiy, правильно, а я был невнимателен в отношении  моего кода и вашего комментария.

Answer (score 2):

Предполагается что строки не заканчиваются висящими пробелами.

https://ideone.com/pjuszl

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  unsigned cur = 0, res = ~0U;
  int x;
  char s[2];
  int n;
  
  while (1)
  {
    n = scanf("%d%1[\n]", &x, s);
    
    if (n > 0)
      ++cur;

    if (n != 1)
    {
      cout << cur << endl;
      if (cur && cur < res) res = cur;
      if (n <= 0) break;
      cur = 0;
    }
  }
  
  cout << "Min is " << res << endl;
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: большое спасибо за ответ, но видимо я немного некорректно объяснил задание, нам необходимо брать данные из файла с помощью библиотеке <fstream>

Comment: @Marlowism, из файла можно считывать через `fscanf` если открыть его с помощью `fopen`.

Comment: error: cannot convert 'const char'* to 'FILE*'

Comment: @Marlowism, `FILE *in = fopen("input.txt");` Давай уже сам, а?